# How to create an object and use it into other methods of a class in C#

Tags: c#, class

I'm trying to write a class which needs to use an object in the other method of the class, consider the Pseudo code :

```
class socket {

private (something to be used by other methods) interface_like_method {
//initializing a socket class
//to be used by other methods
}

public FileTrasfer (ref socket client) {
// here, we can use the initialized obj of interface_like_method 
// client.sendfile("a path") ; 
}
}
```

How such the functionality could be implemented?

Comment: Did you try using a member variable?

Comment: You are looking for something like singleton design pattern, give it a try http://www.dofactory.com/net/singleton-design-pattern

Comment: Please put in more code instead of placeholders, right now it is unclear what you are wanting to do. Show us how you would do it if you could do anything you wanted in the language.

Comment: @Biscuits Seems the answer is somehow what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare a variable as an 'instance variable' (also known as 'member variable'). This means that this variable can be used anywhere in the class. If the variable is declared inside a method, only that method has access to it.

```
class One {
//code
}

class Two {
 One one; //instance variable accessible in entire class, not initialized
 One oneInitialized = new One(); //this one is initialized
 Two() { //this is a constructor
  one = new One(); //initializes the object 'one' that is declared above
 }
 someMethod() {
  One secondOne = new One(); //can only be used inside this method
 }
 //use object 'one' anywhere;
}
```